# How to remove this black/white bar on my shiny app?

Tags: r, shiny

Im working on a shiny web app. My UI code (attached below) includes certain parameters for the CSS design of the menu sidebar. Im trying to get rid of this black/white bar that shows when the side menu is either expanded or not as it takes up some space that i need. Please see pictures at the end of the post

```
    library(shinydashboard)
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(shinyBS)
library(shinymanager)
library(shinythemes)
library(shinyjs)
library(shinyBS)


version='v1.4.1'

set_labels(
  language = "es",
  "Please authenticate" = "Consulta de esquemas de vacunación",
  "Username:" = "Usuario:",
  "Password:" = "Contraseña:"
) 



ui <- secure_app(
             head_auth = tags$script(inactivity),
             theme = shinythemes::shinytheme("cerulean"),
             enable_admin = T,
             tags_top = tags$img(
               src = "logo-s.png", width = 130),
             language = "es",
             fab_position = "bottom-right",
             
             fluidPage(   
                       dashboardPage( 
                     
                     dashboardHeader(
                       
                       
                       title = HTML("Consulta de esquemas de vacunacion"),
                       titleWidth = 300,
                       tags$li(a(href = '.',
                                 img(src = 'logo-s.png',
                                     title = "Reiniciar app", height = "80px"),
                                 style = "padding-top:10px; padding-bottom:10px;"),
                               class = "dropdown"),
                       
                       tags$li(class = "dropdown",
                               tags$style(".main-header {max-height: 80px; }"),
                               tags$style(".main-header .logo {height: 100px;}"),
                               tags$style(".sidebar-toggle {height: 80px; padding-top: 40px !important;}"),
                               tags$style(".navbar {min-height:80px !important}")
                       )            
                       
                       
                     ),
                     
                     dashboardSidebar(
                       width = 225,
                       
                       # Adjust the sidebar
                       tags$style(".left-side, .main-sidebar {top: auto; padding-top: 80px}"),
                       
                       tags$head(tags$link(rel="shortcut icon", href="favicon.png")),
                       
                       sidebarMenu(
                         
                         tags$script(HTML("$('body').addClass('fixed');")),
                         
                         tags$style(HTML('
                                          /* logo */
                                            .skin-blue .main-header .logo {
                                                                  background-color: #173a82;
                                                                  }
                                    
                                            /* logo when hovered */
                                            .skin-blue .main-header .logo:hover {
                                                                  background-color: #173a82;
                                                                  }
                                    
                                            /* navbar (rest of the header) */
                                            .skin-blue .main-header .navbar {
                                                                  background-color: #173a82;
                                                                  }        
                                    
                                            /* main sidebar */
                                            .skin-blue .main-sidebar {
                                                                  background-color: #173a82;
                                                                  }
                                    
                                            /* active selected tab in the sidebarmenu */
                                            .skin-blue .main-sidebar .sidebar .sidebar-menu .active a{
                                                                  background-color: #688ff6;
                                                                  }
                                    
                                            /* other links in the sidebarmenu */
                                            .skin-blue .main-sidebar .sidebar .sidebar-menu a{
                                                                  background-color: #173a82;
                                                                  color: #000000;
                                                                  }
                                    
                                            /* other links in the sidebarmenu when hovered */
                                             .skin-blue .main-sidebar .sidebar .sidebar-menu a:hover{
                                                                  background-color: #5d705d;
                                                                  }
                                            /* toggle button when hovered  */                    
                                             .skin-blue .main-header .navbar .sidebar-toggle:hover{
                                                                  background-color: #5d705d;
                                                                  }
                                                                  ')),
        
        hr(style = "border-top: 1px solid #46575e;"),
        div(id="container6", style = "color :#FFFFFF;  ", h4('Consultas ')),
        
        menuItem("COVID-19 + Vacunacion infantil", tabName = "principal1", icon = icon("syringe")),
               
        hr(style = "border-top: 1px solid #46575e;"),
        
        div(id="container5", style = "position: absolute; bottom: 0; color :#b8c7ce;  ", 
            h6(paste(version)), 
        ))
        
                     ),
        
        dashboardBody(
          
          br(),
                   
          tabItems(
            
            tabItem(tabName = "principal1",
                    br(),
                    
                    fluidRow( 
                      column(2,
                             textInput(inputId = "documento1", "Ingrese el numero de documento", "")
                             ),
                      
                      column(2,
                             br(),
                             fluidRow(
                               actionButton("consulta_gobutton1", 
                                            label =  "Procesar",
                                            icon = icon("clipboard-check") ) #,
                               
                                ))
                      ),
                    
                    fluidRow(
                      hr(style = "border-top: 1px solid #b8c2cf;")),       
                    
                    fluidRow(
                      column(4,
                             h3("Datos del usuario"),
                             htmlOutput("text2")
                      )),
                    
                    fluidRow(
                      column(12,
                             h3("Esquema de vacunación "), 
                             DT::dataTableOutput("table1") 
                      ))),
            
            )
        )
    ))
```

[image: when sidebar is expanded]

[image: when sidebar is contracted]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have

```
ui <- fluidPage(   dashboardPage( ...))
```

change it to

```
ui <- dashboardPage(... )
```

to remove the space on left and right sides.